# How to retain selected rows in datatable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Here is how I created the datatable

```
<table id="@nameof((OrderViewModel.Orders)" 
       data-bind="datatable: @nameof((OrderViewModel.Orders), datatableOptions: getTableOptions('@nameof((OrderViewModel.Orders)')" 
       class="table table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap datatable-style" 
       cellspacing="0">
</table>
```

I need to keep selected rows selected after executing update action, I call a search method in order to refresh the datatable (I know it is not the best way to do it) so all the selected items will be lost.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map of the selected data key fields before sending your ajax to update.
Upon success and when you search the database and get results back, you can then compare your original selection and re-mark any previously selected rows as marked.
Assuming there is a property `.isSelected` to mark your model as a selected model:

Before ajax :

```
var selectedKeys = myArray.filter(function(item){ return item.isSelected(); }).map(funcion(item){ return item.KeyFieldToLookFor(); })
```

Then upon getting the new data back:

```
success: function(data){
   if(data && data.length)
      data.forEach(function(item){ 
      if(selectedKeys.contains(item.KeyFieldToLookFor())
     {
        item.isSelected(true);
     }
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response , I don't have the property isSelected, I have an array with selected items Ids how to highlight rows in javascript